# jQuery, multiple content sliders in single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I want to make a lot of slides in a one-page scrolling site. A neat way to do this was with a code from [Stano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422309/stano). My problem is that this code was only meant to occur once per page. In order to make it fit my needs I made it into [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmagnez/gos1xq93/). I realized that this would accumulate very fast into some rather messy coding if I had 20+ of these:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var divs = $('.divs>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide().first().show(); // hide all divs except first
    $(".next").click(function() {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
    });
    $(".prev").click(function() {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show previous
    });
});
```

Is there any way to create a common ID/class for the divs and clickers (previous, next) or a container that ensures that the slider functions by itself without interrupting other sliders?

For example creating a variable with the ID of the container

```
var test = $('.container').attr('id') )
```

Implementing the ID in the divs

```
var divs = $(test).attr( 'id',$(test).attr('id') );
```

Implementing the ID in the next (and prev), so that when they are being clicked they will only affect the divs with the same ID

```
$(".next",test).click(function () {...
```

Maybe have a wrapper with a specific ID where the 3 divs (divs, prev and next) are includes and tell the script that they need to be in the same wrapper in order to affect each other.

```
<div ID="wrap1">
<div class="prev"></div>
<div class="next"></div>
<div class="divs"></div>
</div>
```

I do not know how the script will change. Maybe including .child() or .parent()?

I am very new at java scripting and hope that my question is understood properly. Please let me know if there is anything that needs to be clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Check my code, each slider has now a function at document ready, not mixing thing around, and a jquery higher version was used.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  function FirstSlider(){
    var divs = $('.div1>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    console.log(divs);
    divs.hide().first().show(); // hide all divs except first
    $(".nex1").click(function () {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
    });
    $(".pre1").click(function () {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show previous
    });
  }

   function SecondSlider(){
    var divs = $('.div2>div');
    var now = 0; // currently shown div
    divs.hide().first().show(); // hide all divs except first
    $(".nex2").click(function () {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show next
    });
    $(".pre2").click(function () {
        divs.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
        divs.eq(now).show(); // show previous
    });
 }
    FirstSlider();
    SecondSlider();
});
```

```css
.body {
    margin: 0 0;
}
.prenex {
    position: fixed;
    top:15vh;
    display: block;
    background-color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 10vh;
    padding: 2vh 4vh;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    /* Chrome/Safari */
    -moz-user-select: none;
    /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none;
    /* IE10+ */
}
.prev, .pre1, .pre2 {
    left:5vh;
    float:left;
}
.next, .nex1, .nex2 {
    right: 5vh;
    float:right;
}
.pre1, .nex1 {
    top:20vh;
}
.pre2, .nex2 {
    top:70vh;
}
.divs, .div1, .div2 {
    width:70vw;
    height:40vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    background-color:#aaa;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prenex nex1">></div>
<div class="prenex pre1">
    <</div>
        <div class="div1">
            <div>Hello World,</div>
            <div>I</div>
            <div>Am</div>
            <div>The</div>
            <div>Test</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div class="prenex nex2">></div>
        <div class="prenex pre2">
            <</div>
                <div class="div2">
                    <div>Hello World,</div>
                    <div>why do I</div>
                    <div>follow</div>
                    <div>the steps of</div>
                    <div>my evil twin?</div>
                </div>
```